# Im not able to decode my file passed from JAVASCRIPt to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am encoding and  passing a file (word document) to php.How can I read this and write to a file?

I have submit button.On submit, I am passing an ajax.Before that, Iam encoding the file with file reader.On submit button, an event 'handleFileSelect' is trtiggered.The file is read as dataurl and sent to php via ajax.

I am able to get the data as encoded.If the file is a text, i am also able to decode .But 
its not able to get the contents of a word file.If I decode
How would I do this?

My code :

```
//File Convertion--Function to convert images to base 64 encoded format
function handleFileSelect(objEvent) {
  var strFiles = objEvent.target.files; // FileList object
  strInput = document.getElementById('uploaded_file');
  strFile = strInput.files[0];
  strFiletype=strFile.type;
  strFileSize=strFile.size;alert(strFiletype);
  strFiletype=strFiletype.split("/");

  //Checking wheter the uploaded file is image or not
  if(strFiletype[0]!='image') {
    for (var i = 0, f; f = strFiles[i]; i++) { 
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
              return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    strGlobalImageData=e.target.result;
              };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    } 
  } else {
        alert("NOT A DOC");
  }
 }
//ajax call to send files to php
var app = 'contact.php';
$.ajax({
    url: app,
    async: false,
    type:"POST",
    data : "file="+strGlobalImageData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    processData:false,
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success: function(html) {
         alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    }
});

//Php side--contact.php
<?php
$files=base64_decode($_POST['file']);
```

If I decode, I am getting a binary format of the word file

Comment: you may consider to edit your question for easy reading .... No one willing to read wall of your question..

Comment: @linn u are passing doc to the php or data in word document to php ?

Comment: Hi,iam passing doc to php.But it will be in the encoded format.                                                eg: If I type die($_POST['file']), I get                                                                                          data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQB4PzowwwEAAOUHAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLn

Comment: :):I got it......I tried my own way and I got it.I am answering now below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with character replacing.We need to replace befor decoding the data.The exact code is shown below:
In Php,

$files=trim($_POST['file']);

$strEncodedData= str_replace(' ','+',$files);

$strFilteredData = explode(',',$strEncodedData);

$strDecodedData= base64_decode($strFilteredData[1]);

$arrFiles = explode(",",$files);

file_put_contents("myfile.doc",$strDecodedData);

This content will be written into file "myfile.doc".

Thank you for all effort made by my friends